# Laravel - View [layouts.master] not found

Tags: php, laravel, layout, laravel-blade, templating

I'm making the Laravel tutorial step by step but the @extends is making me error that is View [layouts.master] not found. My layouts folder is in resources/views/layouts and my master.blade.php in the layouts folder. My connexion.blade.php is in resources/views/connexion.blade.php, so with the @extends('layouts.master') I'm not supposed to got any error. I'm maked the laravel tutorial perfectly but it seems to be strange.

RESOURCES/VIEWS/CONNEXION.BLADE.PHP

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('titre', 'Connexion')

@section('body')

@stop
```

RESOURCES/VIEWS/LAYOUTS/MASTER.BLADE.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site Panel - @yield('titre')</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    @yield('body')
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not NOT FOUND but FILE PERMISSION why laravel dev didn't make PERMISSION DENIED instead of NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0):

Hold up.... `My layouts folder is in resources/views/layouts and my master.blade.php in the layouts folder.`

So that means your `master.blade.php` is inside `resources/views/layouts/layouts`? That would mean the extend function would be `@extend('layouts.layouts.master')`

Answer (score 0):

```
Blade Templates
Layout
// Extend your theme layout
@extends('layouts.master')
// Start section
@section('title')
// End Section
@endsection
@parent
// Show section in your theme
@yield('name')
// Include view in your file
@include('view.name')
// Include view with pass data
@include('view.name', ['key' => 'value']);
```